# Failed opening the RDB file authorized_keys (in server root dir /run) for saving: Permission denied

Tags: docker, redis

i've a docker with redis container

configuration of it

docker-compose.yml

```
# Redis
redis:
  image: redis:4.0.6
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: dockerfile_redis
  volumes:
    - "./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

dockerfile_redis

```
CMD ["chown", "redis:redis", "-R", "/etc"]
CMD ["chown", "redis:redis", "-R", "/var/lib"]
CMD ["chown", "redis:redis", "-R", "/run"]

CMD ["sudo", "chmod", "644", "/data/dump.rdb" ]
CMD ["sudo", "chmod", "755", "/etc" ]
CMD ["sudo", "chmod", "770", "/var/lib" ]
CMD ["sudo", "chmod", "777", "/run" ]

CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

Also i use django and celery, when celery works 4-6 hours, container of celery stopped, with error:

```
[2018-03-05 17:18:24,516: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ResponseError('MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for details about the RDB error.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 370, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 320, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 596, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 88, in asynloop
    next(loop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 354, in create_loop
    cb(*cbargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 1040, in on_readable
    self.cycle.on_readable(fileno)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 337, in on_readable
    chan.handlers[type]()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 714, in _brpop_read
    **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 680, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 629, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for details about the RDB error.
Import Error

 -------------- celery@b17b82a69031 v4.1.0 (latentcall)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-34-generic-x86_64-with-debian-8.9 2018-03-05 07:24:00
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         backend:0x7f19e5745208
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 20 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . CallbackNotifier
  . FB posting
  . FB token status
  . MD posting
  . MD token status
  . OK posting
  . OK token status
  . TW posting
  . TW token status
  . VK posting
  . VK token status
  . api.controllers.message.scheduled_message
  . backend.celery.debug_task
  . stats.views.collect_stats
```

In my redis.conf file i disable snapshots

```
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
```

In redis logs:

```
 1:M 06 Mar 07:40:04.037 * Background saving started by pid 8228
 8228:C 06 Mar 07:40:04.038 # Failed opening the RDB file backupall.db (in server root dir /run) for saving: Permission denied
```

But, when i restart redis container i've get some warnings:

```
1:C 06 Mar 08:12:48.982 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
 1:C 06 Mar 08:12:48.982 # Redis version=4.0.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
 1:C 06 Mar 08:12:48.982 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
 1:M 06 Mar 08:12:48.986 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
 1:M 06 Mar 08:12:48.986 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
 1:M 06 Mar 08:12:48.986 # Server initialized
 1:M 06 Mar 08:12:48.987 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
 1:M 06 Mar 08:12:48.988 * DB loaded from disk: 0.001 seconds
 1:M 06 Mar 08:12:48.988 * Ready to accept connections
```

1. Permissions in dockerfile_redis is correct?
2. How configurate redis with my conf file?
3. What also i need to make the redis work well?

Comment: Your Redis is probably exposed to the world, not protected with a password, and was therefore compromised by a malicious person.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this blogpost:

https://blog.huntingmalware.com/notes/LLMalware

It is very likely a malware causing the working directory of your redis to change, and redis tries to write RDB file to a directory owned by root, following the commands of a malicious script. As it does not run from root, and write access to /run directory is not granted to user 'redis', the writing fails.

So, do not expose your Redis server port to the Internet and it should fix the issue with malware being able to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not really need to expose ports, just remove next lines:

```
ports:
  - "6379:6379"
```